# 'Spline' tool in ArcGIS Pro keeps dropping collinear points

Tags: coordinate-system, arcgis-pro, maxent, spline

I am trying to convert the WorldClim dataset from their original resolution of 30 arc-seconds (WGS1984) to 25m cells (OSGB British National Grid) for use in Maxent modelling.

I clipped the individual raster files (bioclim1, bioclim2 etc.) to my study area in south Wales and converted to OSGB using the 'Project raster' tool. I then converted the resulting files to point using 'Raster to point' and ran the 'Spline' tool with 25m as my new cell size.

The tool succeeded but included multiple warnings saying that 'collinear points have been dropped'. What does this mean? Is the tool designed to drop collinear points (which doesn't make much sense to me intellectually) or have I done something wrong?

For those with experience in Maxent modelling: Do I even need to go through all this or can I just use the original data in their original projection and resolution?

Comment: Just resample your projected raster to 25 m using cubic ....